# How to replace this switch - case with a Dictionary<string, Func<>>?

Tags: c#, refactoring, func

I hate switch - cases. I am trying to refactor a switch - case in my code which looks like the following:

```
int i = 0;
string str = string.empty;

switch (color)
{
    case "red":
        i = MyIntArgsFunction(1, 2);

    case "blue":
        str = MyStringArgsFunction("cat", "dog");
}


private int MyIntArgsFunction(int x, int y)
{
    // Implementation
}

private string MyStringArgsFunction(string s, string t)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

I would like to add the 2 functions MyIntArgsFunction and MyStringArgsFunction into a Dictionary> structure and then invoke the appropriate function depending on the color the user chooses. But due to the difference in arguments to them, I am unable to arrive at a suitable signature for the Func delegate.

Could someone help out please?

Nihal

Comment: Why are you trying to create a delegate at all?  What is the need?  Can you explain or show a little bit more about what your trying to achieve?

Comment: Pass as `object`s and cast.

Comment: No, that's not a good suggestion at all.  http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/csharp/HL1W121013-Understanding-Boxing-and-Unboxing-in-C  http://www.monitis.com/blog/2012/04/26/improving-net-application-performance-part-9-boxing-and-unboxing/

Comment: Looks like you may want *two* dictionaries: one for `integer` functions and one for `string` ones

Comment: I think he just wants to get rid of the `switch-case` to do this: `myFuncDict[color](myArg1, myArg2);`

Comment: Yes, what I want to do is get rid of switch - case. And the code I have added above is only skeletal in nature, the actual code I am trying to refactor has 9 cases to switch through, and the functions to be executed by each switch is more complex. Hope I have made it clearer now. And I am not in favor of the pass in objects and cast suggestion, because of the amount of boxing and unboxing involved.

Comment: For the specific case you've given you could use a `Dictionary<string, Func<Tuple<string, int>>`.  And "red" would map to `() => Tuple.Create(string.Empty, MyIntArgsFunction(1, 2))` for example.  But depending on your actual use case this might get messy.

Comment: 1 -2 and "Cat" "Dog" are always the same?

Comment: In my real world code, I don't need to assign my functions to the variables i or str located outside the switch construct. I am good enough with returning the values of the function calls, as in `return MyIntArgsFunction(1, 2)`

Comment: @Anestis Kivranoglou, no they are not same always. 1, 2 may be -5, -7 at another time, and "cat", "dog" may be "cow", "sheep" at another time

Comment: @AgoodbullnamedNihal How you generate input info? Is it dependcy on color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like hell, but it works :)

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var blueHandler = new Action<string, string>((x, y) => { });
        var redHandler = new Action<int, int>((x, y) => { Console.WriteLine(x);});

        var redStr = "Red";
        var blueStr = "Blue";

        var colorSelector = new Dictionary<string, Invoker>();
        var a = 10;
        var b = 20;
        colorSelector.Add(redStr, new Invoker(redHandler, a, b));
        colorSelector.Add(blueStr, new Invoker(blueHandler, a, b));

        colorSelector["Red"].Invoke();
    }

    public class Invoker
    {
        private Delegate _handler;
        public object[] _param;
        public Invoker(Delegate handler, params object[] param)
        {
            _param = param;
            _handler = handler;
        }

        public void Invoke()
        {
            _handler.DynamicInvoke(_param);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks pal, I like your solution!

Comment: Is that fits your requirements?

Comment: @Mitklantekuli yes you have given me an idea to implement! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A Scholar would suggest the "Object Oriented" Approach. 
Sadly the factory pattern needs a switch case, your stated that you "Hate switch cases" although it would be wise to state also the specific reason.
I suppose it's all about code clarity and "Case" plug in availability
This is my approach avoiding a switch case.

```
public abstract class ColorHandler
{
    public String str { get; set; }
    public int i { get; set; }
    public abstract void Handle();
    public static ColorHandler ColorHandlerFactory(String color,ref int i, ref string str)
    {
        ColorHandler handler = Handlers[color];
        handler.i = i;
        handler.str = str;
        handler.Handle();
        return handler;
    }
    public static Dictionary<String, ColorHandler> Handlers = new Dictionary<string, ColorHandler> ()
    {
        {"red",new RedHandler{myInt1 = 1,myInt2 =2,}},
        {"blue",new BlueHandler{MyStr1="str1",MyStr2="str2"} }
    };
    public Dictionary<String, ColorHandler> InitHandlers(int myNum1,int myNum2,string myStr1,string myStr2){
        return new  Dictionary<string, ColorHandler>()
    {
        {"red",new RedHandler{myInt1 = myNum1,myInt2 =myNum2}},
        {"blue",new BlueHandler{MyStr1=myStr1,MyStr2=myStr2} }
    };
    }

}
public class RedHandler : ColorHandler
{
    public int myInt1 { get; set; }
    public int myInt2 { get; set; }
    public override void Handle()
    {
        this.i = myInt1+myInt2;
        // OR alternatively
        //this.myInt1 = AnExternalFunction(myInt1, myInt2);
    }
}
public class BlueHandler : ColorHandler
{
    public String MyStr1 { get; set; }
    public String MyStr2 { get; set; }
    public override void Handle()
    {
        this.str = MyStr1 + MyStr2;
        // OR alternatively
        //this.myInt1 = AnExternalFunction(MyStr1, MyStr2);
    }
}

public class Doer
{
    public void DoThings()
    {
        int i = 0;
        string str = string.Empty;
        var handler =ColorHandler.ColorHandlerFactory("red",ref i,ref str);
        handler.InitHandlers(1, 2, "Cat", "Dog");
        //Read Results.
        var result=handler.i;


    }
}
```

You can alter Structure to Support Batch Handling also.
Handlers  is the Default initialization of values.
And InitHandler is a function in case you want to override those values.

Answer (score 0):

https://elegantcode.com/2009/01/10/refactoring-a-switch-statement/

The author Chris Brandsma has provided another useful approach to using Dictionary based Factory. Also note the comments of Henrik Gustafsson this provides a polymorphic approach to implementing factory.

According to Henrik Gustafsson:

"A switch statement can usually be replaced by the careful application of polymorphism. If you refactor such that the switch statement is the only thing in a method, and each entry in the switch statement calls only another method, then the state for each case and each method can usually be grouped into its own subclass. As a bonus you’d get your cyclomatic complexity down

Turning

```
class X {
void m() {
switch(…) {
case A:
m_A();
break;
…
}
}
}
```

into

```
class X {
IM _m;
void m() {
_m.dostuff();
}
}

interface IM {
void dostuff();
}

class MA extends IM {
public void dostuff() {
…
}
}
```

This, of course can be quite verbose, so I’ve found myself using variants of the dict trick before.

Misko Hevery has some interesting insights on this in this Google Tech-talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc "

Comment: I highly recommend adjusting indentation for better code readability